# Is it possible to link a static library, built with STL, with a dynamic library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl

I have a static C++ library. The code in the library uses STL containers internally. I want to link this library to a dynamic library. During the build I am getting errors:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
```

related to objects (containers) from STL. I know that there are problems when exporting STL containers from the DLL; however, my library which contains STL is static, so no containers are exported.

Is it possible to link a static library with a dynamic library, if the static library contains STL containers?

Comment: ***Is it possible to link a static library with a dynamic library, if the static library contains STL containers?*** Yes, I have done that. Nothing special needed to make it work.

Comment: "*however, my library which contains STL is static, so no containers are exported.*" Linking statically does not mean symbols or "containers"  aren't exported. Please clarify.

Comment: Please add the full text of the error message to your question.

Comment: I assumed the OP meant that STL was not used in the public dll interface.

Comment: @drescherjm: that's, correct

Comment: Your unresolved external symbol error has absolutely nothing to do with potential problems of having STL (whatever it is) here or there. These problems, when they exist, do not manifest themselves as unresolved external symbols.

Comment: Presumably you've selected the static msvc runtime in your static library? That doesn't link in the runtime library symbols you need to do that when building your dll by selecting the static runtime there as well. You can't mix different runtimes within a single dll

Comment: @AlanBirtles: problem is with the Runtime Library. The Runtime library was Multi-threaded Debug DLL instead of Multi-threaded Debug. Thanks.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution. I would appreciate it if you could write your solution as an answer and mark it. Because this will be beneficial to other community and help others.